# Retain the order of fields during creation in Orchard CMS custom forms

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I created a [custom form](http://orchardcustomforms.codeplex.com/), and adding the fields in a specific order. The form is like a questionnaire wherein the next question is a follow-up of the previous question(s) above it.

I tried modifying the placement.info file, but I can only modify the sequence per control type (numeric before datetime, boolean before text)...

I tried making the order number the same,  in the hopes that the "default" ordering of fields at the time of creation will take over - no joy.

```
<Place Fields_Input_Edit="Content:2.0"/>
<Place Fields_Input="Content:after"/>
<!-- Numeric -->
<Place Fields_Numeric_Edit="Content:2.0"/>
<Place Fields_Numeric="Content:after"/>
```

So I guess the next step here is to use the Shape Designer, inspect the "widget" and override it (Shape->Alternate-Create)? It generates a file (e.g. Widget-url-membership-online-application.cshtml ), and I guess I will start working from this file?

The contents of the file just shows this:

```
@Display(Model.Content)
```

How do I address a specific field such I can do something like:

```
<label for="FirstName">@T("Your First Name")</label>
<input id="FirstName" class="text" name="FirstName" type="text" value="@Model.??????"/>
```

There must be an easier way!

Comment: Did you try the "Edit placement" button in the content type editor?

Comment: Hmnn, when I clicked Save after moving things around, upon page refresh, the order is messed up

Comment: Yes, there is a known bug in there: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18894

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Edit Placement button in the content type editor, or...

You can target a specific field by following the instructions here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info#"Place"Element

For example, `<Place Fields_Common_Text-Occupation="Content:2"/>`

You can also use Match tags to target a specific content type or a specific URL (see that same topic I pointed to above).

Comment: Hmnn, when I clicked Save after moving things around, upon page refresh, the order isn't the one that I designed earlier